# Is is possible to send message using WebSocket after rest called in spring boot?

Tags: websocket, spring-websocket, java-websocket

Is it possible to send messages using WebSocket after rest called in spring boot?
Please help correct me,
I have some configure as below

```
//Use to handle connection and text message
Class SignalHandler extent TextWebSocketHandler{

}

@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {
    private final SignalHandler signalHandler;
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(signalHandler, "/signal")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletServerContainerFactoryBean createWebSocketContainer() {
        ServletServerContainerFactoryBean container = new ServletServerContainerFactoryBean();
        container.setMaxTextMessageBufferSize(8192);
        container.setMaxBinaryMessageBufferSize(8192);
        return container;
    }
}
```

Currently, it's working fine, if I create a WebSocket connection from Web or mobile by point to **http://localhost:8080/signal** to join/leave/message which handles on SignalHandler.

In my case, I have a rest request on backend, after success called, I would like to send message to all client who are in room.

Please you advice me, how can I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest here is to use STOMP (https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/) , which is an application level protocol over the raw web sockets. It gives abstraction as queues and topics which are easier to use.
Coming to your question, I think you might want to redesign your apis to use websocket completely. For e.g. you can use topic to broadcast your message whenever somebody joins.